# Void Functions, cout statements, and compilers

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc

This is something I have noticed and I do not have the answer to it and it bothers me.

Let's say we have two simple functions.

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "Rainbows are cute!" << std::endl;
    return;


}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;

}
```

Now these two functions are all part of the same cpp file.

If I compile this cpp file on gcc the file will cout "Rainbows are cute!" 
but if I were to do it on Xcode or Visual Studio, the cout statement will not display. I mention VS and Xcode because these are two common compilers, used by many.

My question is why does this happen? What is going on in the compilers were one will display the cout statement in the void functions and the others will not?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code or the compilers. I expect it is user error: Where did you expect the output to show up? Did you run it from a console? Running it from the IDE probably is not going to make it print where you thought (i.e. in the output window).

Comment: I didn't say there was anything with the code or compilers. I was saying it does not automatically display on some compilers where as it does on others.And yes I expected it to show up on a console.

Comment: It always displays somewhere, and at least in the case of VS, in a window you can see. It just doesn't stay around after your program terminates.

Comment: Gotcha. I do not use xcode or vs, I use gcc so when I was asked this question I didn't have an answer so I felt stupid.

Comment: If you run the program from the XCode IDE, console out goes to the debug window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printouts will display in VS and Xcode as well. The difference is in how you run this. When you execute your program from Visual Studio, console window briefly pops up, displays the message, and promptly disappears.

To prevent this from happening, you can set breakpoint on `return 0` line, and run in debug mode. When the breakpoint is hit, switch to the console window to see the message:

[image: RainbowsAreCute]

Comment: Thank you for your knowledge. Learn something every day.

Comment: I should have elaborated that I do not use vs or xcode, so I did not know how they operated. But, your example is much appreciated.

Comment: @MipsMoreLikeWhips, it's actually an O/S thing, not an IDE/compiler thing.  In a window-based O/S (like Windows), when you attempt to execute a "console" application that ends immediately, the UI (via a Console window) may or may not be noticed.  You would get the same response independent of launching it via the IDE (say via the Run... dialog or via a CreateProcess call from another application), neither of which know or care how the console application was developed.